# Clicking on a link using VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, hyperlink

I try to automate some handling on a webpage. I have read all the articles I could find, but it just does not fit.

This is partial the webpage:

[image: Webpage with data to retrieve]

This is the HTML beneath:

```html
<div class="rgWrap rgArrPart2">
<a title="Go to Next Page" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00j','')">Volgende</a>
<input type="submit" name="ctl003" value=" " title="Next Page" class="rgPageNext" /> 
<a title="Go to Last Page" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl004','')">Laatste</a>
<input type="submit" name="ctl005" value=" " title="Last Page" class="rgPageLast" />
```

"Volgende" en "Laatste" are Dutch for "Next" and "Last".

The code which I try to build needs to click on the "Volgende" so I get the next page with records.

I have tried the following code:

- `GetElementById()`:

  ```
  IE.Document.GetElementById("ctl00j").Click()
  ```
- `GetElementsByTagName()` and filter by value:

  ```
  Set oInputs = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
  For Each elm In oInputs
      If elm.Value = "Go to Next Page" Then
          elm.Click
          Exit For
      End If
  Next
  ```
- `GetElementsByClassName()`:

  ```
  For Each elem In IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("rgPageNext")
      If elem.innerText = "Go to Next Page" Then
          elem.Focus
          elem.Click
      End If
  Next
  ```
- `GetElementsByTagName()` and filter by `class` attribute:

  ```
  For Each a In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
      If a.GetAttribute("class") = "rgPageNext" Then
          a.Click
          Exit For
      End If
  Next
  ```
- `GetElementsByTagName()` and filter by `title` attribute:

  ```
  For Each a In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If a.getAttribute("title") = "Go to Next Page" Then
      a.Click
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  ```

The first approach gives this error message:

> Script:    K:\temp\TT\mftt.vbs
>   Line:    37
>   Char:    2
>   Error:    Object required: 'IE.Document.getElementByID(...)'
>   Code:    800A01A8
>   Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error

The other attempts are not giving error messages but also no reaction on the link to click. I'm missing here the `OnClick` event. With other links in this project the `OnClick` event was present. I can't change the HTML, so I'm stuck.

UPDATE1: Added the code so far. I'm only busy with clicking on links. I have no process flow or iterations build in. That will come next.

```
    ' // Login procedure for ... //
Dim WshShell
Dim IE
Dim strLoginName
Dim strPassword

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
SET IE = Nothing

Call LogIn

Function LogIn
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.mijn.nl/"
    Wait IE,500
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_Login1_UserName").value = "username"
        .getElementByID("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_Login1_Password").value = "password"
        .getElementByID("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_Login1_LoginButton1").Click()
    End With
    Wait IE, 500
    IE.Navigate "https://www.mijn.nl/deelnemerlijst.aspx"
    'now we have the page where we can select the clients
    Wait IE, 500
    With IE.Document
        'by clicking the 'search' button, we create a client list 
        .getElementByID("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_zoekLanguageButton").Click()
        Wait IE, 500
        'in the client list we select the first one
        'here I need to make a iteration for all the clients
        .getElementById("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl04_DeelnemerKodeLinkButton").Click()
        Wait IE, 500
    End With
    'We go to the transction overview page
    IE.navigate "https://www.mijn.nl/Overzichten/TransactionOverview.aspx"
    Wait IE, 1500
    'here I need to click on ">" on the page to open details I need to extract
    'There are max 10 lines
    ' [ some iteration code ] 
    'click on next transaction page
    For Each a In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If a.getAttribute("title") = "Go to Next Page" Then
        a.Click
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
End Function

Sub Wait(IE, SleepInterval)
    Do
        WScript.Sleep SleepInterval
    Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 Or IE.Busy
End Sub

SET IE = Nothing
```

Comment: Since the link for **Volgende** has no `id` or `name` attribute, perhaps if you modify attempt 4) by changing `If a.getAttribute("class")="rgPageNext"` *(btw you missed "Then" there)* into `If a.getAttribute("title") = "Go to Next Page" Then` ?

Comment: @Theo: I have tried your suggestion, but still nog reaction from de web page. The " Then" in de If statement was in the code but forgotten during entering in this post.

Comment: Did you created and assign the value for IE object? or you are directly using it? If you did not created it then try to create it first then try to use it. also check that IE is in a ready state and then try to click the button. try to debug the code to check that whether it is matching the title value or not. Try to post the full code. we will try to make a test with it.

Comment: @deepak-MSFT; code is now in the question.